# MySQL Save Float Error

Tags: mysql, double, decimal, rounding

Try saving this number into any float or double field
**588966.68**

SQL query will do its thing and save the date and return success. Now retrieve the same value that you just saved, it will say **588966.69**

You saved **.68** and on read you get **.69**!!?!

How is this possible? My field type is FLOAT(10,2) also tried with DOUBLE(12,2) with DECIMAL(12,2) and DECIMAL(12,3) although i need explicit 2 decimals only.

I noticed this happening with numbers over 120K

Comment: Which SQL dbms are you using? Version?

Comment: @PieroAlberto noticed this on Amazon Aurora also did tests on Server version: 5.7.18-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL) with InnoDB

Comment: There is no reason to every use `(m,n)` on `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FLOAT` has 24 *bits* of precision.  Numbers *up to* 128K need 17 bits to represent the integer part, leaving only 7 bits for the fractional part.

Between 128K and 256K: 18 bits for the integer; only 6 bits for the fraction.  6 bits gives you 64 different values -- but 2 decimal places need 100 different values.  Not enough precision.

Comment: Thats very good explanation. The lesson is now learned. Dont use FLOAT on financial software :)

Answer (score 0):

Scratch that it works with **DECIMAL** field type!